# How do I open / wait for a program to finish in C++ then run another?

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am basically thinking of making a christmas gift got my girlfriend that will incorporate a LOT of different things that I've worked on in C++ and a few sentimental things (powerpoint slideshow, etc. etc.) that I want to play out sequentially.  Example, powerpoint presentation segues into a video, segues into displaying a folder with lots of stuff that I wanted to display in it, segues back to a video... etc.

I was hoping that I could use some kind of run command in C++ (I know I could use system, but that's still not going to work on certain mime types).

Does anyone have a workable solution for this, I plan on bountying this so quality answers will be considered and rewarded appropriately!

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: Creating and waiting for a new process is operating system specific. On a Unix derived system, you can use `fork()`, `exec()`, and `wait()`.

Since you mention powerpoint, you are probably running Windows. It would benefit you to tag appropriately.

Comment: Any answer would have to be platform-specific, but you haven't told us what platform you're working on.

Comment: I thought boost::process was supposed to be solve this problem in a platform independent way.

Comment: @Caleb: Aren't most things in programming platform-specific?  That's why we have programming languages and libraries that abstract away those differences.

Comment: Why will `std::system` not work (what does you mean when you say it won't work on certain mime types)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a process from another process, you get a "handle" for the started process; with this handle you can interact with the process (kill it, wait till it exits, poll for its exit status, etc). On Windows see CreateProcess, GetExitCodeProcess and WaitForSingleObject [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=91633).